# Why does I have to click 2-3 times in order to get the registration form to work?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented a registration form that checks for duplicate username
and email before proceeding to store the information to the database as well as creating the Authorization key for each user.

I have tried almost everything I know yet I am still stack.
On the otherhand, some of the devices crash when clicking to the registration form

```
boolean isValid = false;
    boolean isValidEmail = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
       // Log.d(TAG, "validBotsRegisterActivityStart " + isValid + " "  + isValidEmail );

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //currentUserID = mAuth.getUid();
{....}
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
CreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
             CreateNewAccount();
               }
              });
}

private void CreateNewAccount()
    {
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {Toast.makeText(this, "Please add a password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username))
        {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserNames");
            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(username.toLowerCase())) {
                        isValid = false; }
                    else {
                        isValid = true; }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
           });
        }

       if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Emails");
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "SnapshotRegister" + data);

                        if (data.getValue().toString().equals(email))
                        {
                            isValidEmail = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            isValidEmail = true;

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            Log.d(TAG, "userEmail " + email);

        }

       if (isValid = true) {
            if (isValid != isValidEmail)
            { Log.d(TAG, "CreateNewAccount: isValidStepBeforeSend " + isValid + isValidEmail); }
            else { storeUserInformationToDabase(); }
        }
    }

    private void storeUserInformationToDabase()
    {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // loadingBar.dismiss();
                                String s = task.getResult().toString();
                                Log.d(new String("Register : AuthResult"), s);
                                if (s != null) {
                                    String auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                    Log.d(new String("Register : AuthResultUID"), auth);
                                    StoreInfo(s, auth);
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }}}
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Log.d(new String("Register : Exception"), e.getMessage());
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }}); 
}
```

```
private void StoreInfo(String s, String auth) {



        loadingBar.setTitle("Registering.. Please wait");
        loadingBar.show();
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
        userMap.put("username", username);
userMap.put("email", email);

       UsersRef.child(auth).updateChildren(userMap)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Log.d(new String("Register : UsersRefFail"), e);
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

I expect the procedure to start and finish very fast, but the user has to click 2-3 times very fast register button in order to start working

From devices that are crashing before getting to this activity
(from LoginActivity -> RegisterActivity)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Canvas: trying to draw too large(132710400bytes) bitmap.
android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw
```

Logs from hitting the register button

On first Click:

```
2019-06-12 19:33:08.581 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: userName perdon50
2019-06-12 19:33:08.581 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: userEmail main@main.com34
{.........}
2019-06-12 19:33:08.784 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: CreateNewAccount: isValidEmail True
```

On second Click:

```
2019-06-12 19:33:28.995 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: userName perdon50
2019-06-12 19:33:28.995 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: userEmail main@main.com34
2019-06-12 19:33:28.997 4763-4763/apps.stylized W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
2019-06-12 19:33:29.020 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: SnapshotRegisterDataSnapshot { key = 123jsadkkakjcmmcom23, value = active }
2019-06-12 19:33:29.020 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: CreateNewAccount: isValidEmail True
2019-06-12 19:33:29.020 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: SnapshotRegisterDataSnapshot { key = 6b6na2jrsfdw4XPI402EOeLwUpK2, value = main@main.com }
2019-06-12 19:33:29.020 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: CreateNewAccount: isValidEmail True
2019-06-12 19:33:29.020 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: SnapshotRegisterDataSnapshot { key = ATquDl2nmtagb3RgrKaaoho3hJw2, value = main@main.com33 }
{.......}
ps.stylized D/Register Activity :: SnapshotRegisterDataSnapshot { key = vlsMPfiY3dagEjCXH2fyQQSAaWa2, value = kios@kios.com1 }
2019-06-12 19:33:29.024 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: CreateNewAccount: isValidEmail True
2019-06-12 19:33:29.024 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: SnapshotRegisterDataSnapshot { key = waRZgADTM4OMkFgU5eofSkJhxc62, value = main@main.com8 }
2019-06-12 19:33:29.024 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: CreateNewAccount: isValidEmail True
2019-06-12 19:33:29.024 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: SnapshotRegisterDataSnapshot { key = xgWeF0QgGGhWJfQMXhwQPdT1HnR2, value = main@main.com32 }
2019-06-12 19:33:29.024 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: CreateNewAccount: isValidEmail True
2019-06-12 19:33:29.024 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: SnapshotRegisterDataSnapshot { key = yBDzyMkBE6UQdKx72UcDmSQL5JC3, value = main@main.com111 }
2019-06-12 19:33:29.024 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: CreateNewAccount: isValidEmail True
2019-06-12 19:33:29.226 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register Activity :: CreateNewAccount: isValidUsrname True
2019-06-12 19:33:30.299 4763-4813/apps.stylized D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( PhscrFDm9uZnSEpbXhycHyHRSKw1 ).
2019-06-12 19:33:30.299 4763-4813/apps.stylized D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( PhscrFDm9uZnSEpbXhycHyHRSKw1 ).
2019-06-12 19:33:30.299 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
2019-06-12 19:33:30.299 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
2019-06-12 19:33:30.302 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register : AuthResult: com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zze@a968cb6
2019-06-12 19:33:30.302 4763-4763/apps.stylized D/Register : AuthResultUID: PhscrFDm9uZnSEpbXhycHyHRSKw1
```

Comment: Can you provide the crash logs of the devices? This might give us a hint.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @CrimsonMike done.

Comment: @AlexMamo done.

Comment: I cannot see any crash in your log.

Comment: The crash 'Canvas: trying to draw too large(132710400bytes) bitmap.' seems unrelated to the database access. So this might be another problem.

Comment: @CrimsonMike Ok, the crash is fixeable. What about the code, do you see any bugs that could make the precidure of registering work after 2or 3 fast clicks?

Comment: I don't have the experience with the API calls of firebase. What I would recommend is to setup an abstraction that does exactly that. You don't need the UI or any additional code, just the two calls to register a user (then check in firebase if the user exists which is apparently already working) and retrieve the user information from firebase (also working(?)). When making the call without the UI you will fire the event exactly once in a program call. This may add some clearance to the situation and may reveal the problem. Otherwise I may recommend to check the API doc for this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things wrong. You have two booleans `isValid` & `isValidEmail` which is provided value inside Firebase callbacks. You are checking this `isValid != isValidEmail` outside callbacks and code get executed that time when you click button.

Move your condition `isValid != isValidEmail` inside callback.

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserNames");
            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(username.toLowerCase())) {
                        isValid = false; }
                    else {
                        isValid = true; }

             //Here add your next callback 
       DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Emails");
          reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                  {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SnapshotRegister" + data);

                    if (data.getValue().toString().equals(email))
                    {
                        isValidEmail = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValidEmail = true;

                    }
                  if (isValid = true) {
            if (isValid != isValidEmail){
         Log.d(TAG, "CreateNewAccount: isValidStepBeforeSend " + isValid + isValidEmail); 
             }
              else { storeUserInformationToDabase(); }
              }
            }
       }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
           });
```